# How to reduce an array of objects into one object with unique properties? JavaScript

Tags: javascript

How can I reduce an array of objects into one object, with unique properties. I will appreciate any help! Thank you!

```js
const input = 
  [ { "a": false} 
  , { "b": false, "c": true } 
  , { "b": false, "c": true } 
  , { "a": false } 
  , { "b": false, "c": true } 
  , { "b": false, "c": true } 
  , { "b": false, "c": true, "b": false } 
  ] 

// I tried :
  
const object =
  input.reduce( (obj, item) => 
     Object.assign(obj, { [item.key]: item.value })
     , {});

console.log( object );
```

but I get:

```
{ "undefined": undefined }
```

Expected result:

```
{"a":false,"b":false,"c":true}
```

Comment: What do you mean by unique properties?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: You can use `input.reduce()` with proper callback function. You can use `Object.assign()` as a part of it.

Comment: @Nijat Mursali, i mean "a", "b", "c" to be only once

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: @Camilo i tried const object = input.reduce(
  (obj, item) => Object.assign(obj, { [item.key]: item.value }), {}); and i get "object", {
  undefined: undefined
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let input = [
  { a: false },
  { b: false, c: true },
  { b: false, c: true },
  { a: false },
  { b: false, c: true },
  { b: false, c: true },
  { b: false, c: true, b: false },
];

let result = input.reduce((prev, curr) => {
  Object.assign(prev, curr);
  return prev;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

As you can tell, by using the Array.reduce() method, we can reduce the array to an object by initializing the reducer using an empty object ({}) as the second argument of Array.reduce().

And then in the reducer callback, we can work our way up to build the object using the Object.assign() method like how we initially wanted as an end result.

something like this:

```
const inputObject = input.reduce(
    (previousObject, currentObject) => {
        return Object.assign(previousObject, currentObject);
    },
{});

console.log(inputObject);
```

Comment: Do you need to do `[currentObject.id]: currentObject.name`?
Can't you just call the `Object.assign` like `Object.assign(previousObject, currentObject)`?

Comment: the "a", "b", and "c" (from input) could be anything, could have other values, could be "b", "d" and "f"

Comment: @ryy77 it's edited right now :)